# ExtJs4 to ExtJs5 Upgrade: GroupedColumn Chart is not working

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-charts

I am new to Extjs5. I am upgrading extJs4 to ExtJs 5. I am trying to implement a groupedColumn chart but no data shows up only the axises are visible. Even I am not getting any error.
My code is as follows:

```
Ext.define('Result', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    { name: 'state', type: 'string', mapping:0 },
    { name: 'product', type: 'string', mapping:1 },
    { name: 'quantity', type: 'int', mapping:2 }
]
});
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
model: 'Result',
groupField: 'state',
data: [
    ['MO','Product 1',50],
    ['MO','Product 2',75],
    ['MO','Product 3',25],
    ['MO','Product 4',125],
    ['CA','Product 1',50],
    ['CA','Product 2',100],
    ['WY','Product 1',250],
    ['WY','Product 2',25],
    ['WY','Product 3',125],
    ['WY','Product 4',175]
]    
});
Ext.define('Ext.chart.series.AutoGroupedColumn', {
extend: 'Ext.chart.series.Bar',
type: 'autogroupedcolumn',
alias: 'series.autogroupedcolumn',
gField: null,
constructor: function( config ) {
    this.callParent( arguments );
    // apply any additional config supplied for this extender
    Ext.apply( this, config );
    var me = this,
        store = me.chart.getStore(),
        // get groups from store (make sure store is grouped)
        groups = store.isGrouped() ? store.getGroups().items : [],
        // collect all unique values for the new grouping field
        groupers = store.collect( me.gField ),
        // blank array to hold our new field definitions (based on groupers collected from store)
        cmpFields = [];
    // first off, we want the xField to be a part of our new Model definition, so add it first
    cmpFields.push( {name: me.xField } );
    // now loop over the groupers (unique values from our store which match the gField)
   /* for( var i in groupers ) {
        // for each value, add a field definition...this will give us the flat, in-record column for each group 
        cmpFields.push( { name: groupers[i], type: 'int' } );
    }*/

    for (var i = 0; i < groupers.length; i++) {
        var name = groupers[i];
        cmpFields.push({name:name,type:'number'});
    }

    // let's create a new Model definition, based on what we determined above
    Ext.define('GroupedResult', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: cmpFields
    });
    // now create a new store using our new model
    var newStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'GroupedResult'
    });
     // now for the money-maker; loop over the current groups in our store
    for( var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++ ) {
        // get a sample model from the group
        var curModel = groups[ i ].items[ 0 ]; 
        // create a new instance of our new Model
        var newModel = Ext.create('GroupedResult');
        // set the property in the model that corresponds to our xField config
        newModel.set( me.xField, curModel.get( me.xField ) );
        // now loop over each of the records within the old store's current group
        for( var x = 0; x < groups[ i ].items.length; x++) {
            // get the record
            var dataModel = groups[ i ].items[ x ];
            // get the property and value that correspond to gField AND yField
            var dataProperty = dataModel.get( me.gField );
            var dataValue = dataModel.get( me.yField );
            // update the value for the property in the Model instance
            newModel.set( dataProperty, dataValue );
            // add the Model instance to the new Store
            newStore.add( newModel );
        }
    }
    // now we have to fix the axes so they work
    // for each axes...
    me.chart.axes.every( function( item, index, len ) {
        // if array of fields
        if( typeof item.getFields()=='object' ) {
            // loop over the axis' fields
            for( var i in item.fields ) {
                // if the field matches the yField config, remove the old field and replace with the grouping fields
                if( item.getFields(i)==me.yField ) {
                   Ext.Array.erase( item.getFields(), i, 1 );
                   Ext.Array.insert( item.getFields(), i, groupers );
                   break;
                }
            } 
        }
        // if simple string
        else {
            // if field matches the yField config, overwrite with grouping fields (string or array)
            if( item.getFields()==me.yField ) {
                item.setFields(groupers);
            }
        }
    });
    // set series fields and yField config to the new groupers
    me.fields,me.yField = groupers;
    // update chart's store config, and re-bind the store
    me.chart.store = newStore;
    me.chart.bindStore( me.chart.store, true );
    // done!
}
})

Ext.create('Ext.chart.CartesianChart', {
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
width: 500,
height: 300,
animate: true,
store: store,
legend: {
  position: 'right'  
},
axes: [
    {
        type: 'numeric',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['quantity'],
        label: {
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        },
        title: 'Quantity',
        grid: true,
        minimum: 0
    },
    {
        type: 'category',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['state'],
        title: 'State'
    }
],
series: [
    {
        type: 'autogroupedcolumn',
        axis: 'left',
        highlight: true,
        xField: 'state',
        yField: 'quantity',
        gField: 'product'
    }
]
});
```

I have used `Ext.chart.series.Bar` in place of `Ext.chart.series.Column` as `Ext.chart.series.Column` no more valid in ExtJs 5. I also have made other minor essential changes required to make my code compatible to ExtJs 5. You can also check this example on https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hvk .
I have already spent 3 days on it. Please help!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing your constructor in AutoGroupedColumn to initComponent? I'm not sure what your graph is supposed to look like, but this change makes some data appear on your graph.

Comment: Sorry @MonicaOlejniczak, I didn't mention the chart which I am looking for. You can refer to https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i0e . This link contains my code in Extjs4 and it works fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I managed to get this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i4e) so far, but I'm not sure how you've grouped the rest of the chart with setting the series fields, as no method is available for that on a series. If you'd like me to explain what I've got so far, then feel free to ask.

Comment: @MonicaOlejniczak I really appreciate your work. But I am looking for Clustered column chart like http://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i0e. If you can see in Extjs4 the same thing has been implemented in a straight forward manner. But I am not able to achieve the same using Extjs5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Samir, If you want a Grouped Chart which is non-stacked use stacked: false property in series. Modify the code of @MonicaOlejniczak as:

```
legend :{
   docked: right
}
series: {
  .......
  ........
  stacked: false,
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks man.. It really worked. MonicaOlejniczak, thanks again.